# start in-cell-editing a row in primefaces datatable using context menu

Tags: primefaces, contextmenu

I'd like to trigger in-cell-editing in a dataTable from a context menu edit command. I'm using primesfaces 3.4.1. I only found examples for editing using p:column/p:rowEditor (which is working fine). Context-menu examples span delete/view only but not editing.
Thanx in advance
hp